# Show that vector space has no countable base

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

This is one of my homework assignments in linear algebra:

> Show that $\mathbb{F}_7^\mathbb{N}$ has no basis that has a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$.

I think that is wrong. So $\mathbb{F}_7^\mathbb{N}$ is the set of all maps $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{F}_7$. Let

$$
\mu: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{F}_7^\mathbb{N} \text{ with } \mu(1) = (1, 0, 0, ...), \mu(2) = (0, 1, 0, 0, ...), \mu(2) = (0, 0, 1, 0, ...)
$$

So for every $f \in \mathbb{F}_7^\mathbb{N}$ I can write

$$
f = \lambda_1\mu(1) + \lambda_2\mu(2) + ... \text{ with } \lambda_i \in \mathbb{F}_7 \forall i \in I
$$

So $\mu$ clearly defines a basis and is a bijection to $\mathbb{N}$.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: In a vector space you are not allowed to form sums containing infinitely many terms. You need a concept of convergence to be able to do that. Also, a set of vectors $S$ of a vector space $V$ spans $V$ if and only if you can write any vector of $V$ as a **finite** linear combination of vectors of $S$. After all, the set of finite linear combinations is already closed under addition and scalar multiplication. Therefore the subspace spanned by your $\mu(1),\ldots$ only contains sequences with finitely many non-zeros entries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basis for a vector space is a collection of vectors such that any $v \in V$ can be expressed as a **finite** sum of elements of it.

Your proof is kind of a classic argument, prove that $|2^{\mathbb{N}}| = |\mathbb{R}|$. Using that, given any subset of $\mathbb{N}$ how could that define a map...?

Comment: If the dimensionality of a vector space is the number of its basis vectors, how can there be infinite dimensional vector spaces of the set of basis vectors has to be finite?

Comment: The set does not have to be finite, the sums do. Think about the polynomial vector space $\mathbb{R}[x]$. Polynomials are finite sums of $a_i x^i$, but the basis is obviously infinite. If you allow infinite sums, you get a different space $\mathbb{R}[[x]]$

Comment: The key point is that, for infinite dimensional vector space $V$ over $k$, we have $\lvert V\rvert=\lvert k\rvert\cdot\dim V$. (If one cannot prove it on oneself, see http://mathoverflow.net/a/49572)